# Problem parsing files when extracting filenames os.listdir() as

Tags: python, windows

If I use `filename = argv[n]` from a windows command line, the `extract()` function below seems to work okay. If I instead use the list of files names from the `list(dir)`, which uses the `os.listdir()` built-in function to extract the filenames from the working directory, then the `extract()` function fails.

The input_file.read() recognises the filename as a valid value, but it seems to fail at `date = list(date_match[0]`) with 'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found'.

It seems that the os.listdir output list values are not normal strings, but something else instead. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import re
import os

def extract(filename):

    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    data = input_file.read() #read file line by line

    #make list of time and date
    date_match = re.findall(r'(\d+:\d+)\t(\d+/\d+/\d+)', data) #find file date and time
    date = list(date_match[0])

    #extract date tuple from list above
    return date

def list(dir):
    directoryfiles = os.listdir(dir)
    diroutput = []
    for member in directoryfiles:
        if member != sys.argv[0]:
            diroutput.append(member)
    return diroutput

def main():

    inputfiles = list(sys.argv[1])

    for filename in inputfiles:
        date = extract(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try this again after changing the name of the `list` function.  `list` is a python built-in, and you should not override that name.

Comment: what do you mean by "it seems that the os.listdir output list values are not normal strings, but something else", did you try to print values, print there types e.g. `print dir, type(dir)` , btw `dir` is a builtin command don't use it as variable name

Comment: There's also no reason to use `re.findall()` if you're only taking the first result. It'd be much more efficient to just do `date_match = re.search(r'(\d+:\d+)\t(\d+/\d+/\d+)', data);date = filelist(date_match.group())`, where `filelist` is a corrected name for your `list` function (as `list` is a Python builtin and shouldn't be shadowed like that). (Or, if you were wanting to use the builtin `list` there, just rename your `list` function and keep that usage of `list`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've redefined `list`! When you try to do `date = list(date_match[0])`, you're calling your `list` function, not the builtin `list` function. Rename the list function and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was a case of 'not seeing the wood for the trees'